# Plot an axis by converting time over different dates in second

Tags: excel, graph, charts, axis, curve

I have 3 columns of data. First is a temperature column, the next one is a date column and another is a time column. I want to plot a temperature against time graph. How can I plot the time to be a continuous graph. I mean taking into consideration the 2 columns ( date and time ) and maybe converting them to minutes or seconds. Does anyone know how can I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another column that converts your date and time to "date and time" by using

```
SUM(<Date Cell>,<Time Cell>)
```

Excel  would automatically do the date and time addition for you 
Tried this in Excel 2013 and it works well.